# Linq query including null child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

Using entity framework, i am trying to select records and their related child records. The child records could be null, so i would just like to return an empty string if they are. I am getting a

> null reference exception

when attempting to run the following code.

```
var query = ctx.UserAlerts.Include(x=>x.DocumentType).Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList();
var alerts = query.Select(u => new AlertConfigVM
            {
                UserId = u.UserId,
                Destination = u.AlertDestination,
                TypeofAlert = u.TypeofAlert,
                HourInterval = u.IntervalAsHours,
                DocumentTypeName= u.DocumentType.Name??string.Empty
            }).ToList();
```

here are my Entities

```
public class UserAlert
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int TypeofAlert { get; set; }
    public string AlertDestination { get; set; }
    public int? DocumentTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
    public int? IntervalAsHours { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my return type.

```
public class AlertConfigVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int TypeofAlert { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public int? DocumentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentTypeName { get; set; }
    public int? HourInterval { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Make sure documentType is not null before checking if documenttype.name is not null.

Comment: how would i do that? Can you post an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
DocumentTypeName= u.DocumentType.Name??string.Empty
```

to this:

```
DocumentTypeName= u.DocumentType?.Name??string.Empty
```

This will allow the DocumentType to default to string.Empty if null.

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. I didnt realize that you could do that. Where did you pick up that handly little trick?

Comment: Honestly, I "accidentally" discovered it using ReSharper, if I'm honest.

Comment: Note, that this solution **ONLY** works in Visual Studio 2015 and later with MSBuild using Roslyn.

Answer (score 1):

Since [tjcertified's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42397515/2607840) only works in Visual Studio 2015 and later, this solution should work regardless of environment:

```
var query = ctx.UserAlerts.Include(x=>x.DocumentType).Where(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList();
var alerts = query.Select(u => new AlertConfigVM
            {
                UserId = u.UserId,
                Destination = u.AlertDestination,
                TypeofAlert = u.TypeofAlert,
                HourInterval = u.IntervalAsHours,
                DocumentTypeName= u.DocumentType != null 
                                  ? u.DocumentType.Name != null 
                                      ? u.DocumentType.Name 
                                      : string.Empty 
                                  : string.Empty
            }).ToList();
```

The `?:` operation is the [ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4(v=vs.100).aspx) and is the same as a regular `if-else` statement.

Comment: You could make it shorter: (`u.DocumentType == null ? null : u.DocumentType.Name) ?? string.Empty`

Comment: @AndersonPimentel Nice catch. Didn't think about that.